# How do I get the USB drive Path and Label by Vendor Id and Product Id

Tags: usb-drive

I have a USB drive's vendor id and product id (the ones you get in the ID field if you run `lsusb` e.g. `090c:1000`). Now I want to find the USB drive's label and path (the ones you get if you run `sudo blkid` e.g. `/dev/sdb1: LABEL="FOODRIVE"`). Can I get the label and the path by USB drive's vendor id and product id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pretty good listing with

```
lsblk --output NAME,VENDOR,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

This will show you the vendor and product id of your disks, and any partitions and mountpoints they might have.

Comment: Listing /dev/disk/by-id/ displays my USB drive as `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 20 15:37 usb-SMI_USB_DISK-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 20 15:37 usb-SMI_USB_DISK-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
` no vendor or product id there.

Comment: @RobertMugattarov right, apparently USB devices give far less information on `/dev/disk/by-id/`. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: `lsblk --output NAME,VENDOR,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` produces sdb    SMI      USB DISK                                 
└─sdb1                           /media/robert/50DA-951B which seems to be the system generated ID, not the vendor-product id pair(

Comment: @RobertMugattarov For my LaCie USB disk, the VENDOR and MODEL information are correct. What do you think the **vendor id** and **product id** should be?

Comment: For this particular USB drive they are `090c` and `1000` (as in the question).